# Keyboard shortcut to open bookmark manager in Chrome 6?

Tags: google-chrome

Ctrl+Shift+B doesn't work for my anymore. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> together, then press <kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: **This is only a partial workaround**, not the answer to OP's question.
This shortcut opens the dropdown sub-menu "/Bookmarks", **not the Bookmark Manager**. Press **B** again to open the Bookmark Manager using this method.

*note: I upvoted this by mistake, cannot undo (I think because of time limit).*

Answer (score 24):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> opens the bookmark manager in newer versions of chrome.

Comment: This is really the only answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other two are only workarounds: one is a key sequence to reach the bookmark manager via drop-down menu, the other is also keyboard-friendly (with default Chrome configuration), but is not by any means a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter `chrome://bookmarks`

Comment: Not a keyboard shortcut, albeit keyboard-friendly. The OP asked for a **keyboard shortcut**, not an alternative method of reaching the Bookmark Manager.
*note: Upvoted this then changed my mind, unfortunately it's too late to undo.*

Answer (score 0):

**For Macs:** Cmd+Option+B

**For PCs:** Ctrl+Shift+O

For my own reference, I'm using a Microsoft keyboard with a Macbook, so it's **Windows+Alt+B** for me. This is an old question, but it kept coming up whenever I looked for the answer. So it might help others, too.

**Source:** Under "Google Chrome feature shortcuts" dropdown as "Open the Bookmark Manager"
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en